Real degrees after forcing a random real
We know a lot about the properties of the real degrees if we assume the existence of an $L$-generic Cohen real (e.g. see Abraham and Shore Degrees of Constructibility of Cohen Reals). Among other things, we know that there must be a perfect set (in particular, a set of size the continuum) of mutually $L$-generic Cohen reals.
I was wondering what we know about the constructibility degrees in the presence of an $L$-generic random real. In particular:

Where can I find a proof of the fact that random reals don't have minimal degree?
If there exists an $L$-generic random real, are there continuum many mutually $L$-generic random reals?

Thanks
EDIT1: In Kunen's chapter of the Handbook of set-theoretic topology we can find a general iteration theorem from which it follows that random forcing is far from being minimal (Ch. 20, Theorem 3.13). My second question still remains.
EDIT2: the second question has negative answer. It is consistent, by a result of Judah and Shelah (Set theory: on the structure of the real line, Theorem 3.2.29), that there exists an $L$-generic random real and that the set of all $L$-generic random reals has cardinality strictly less than continuum.

Kunen's theorem is not needed for your first question: if $r\in 2^\omega$ is random over $L$ then so is the "every other bit" real $2r$, whose $i$th bit is $r$'s $2i$th bit (formally, $2r=\lambda x.r(2x)$). But $2r$ is strictly below $r$ in the constructibility order. (Note that this is exactly the same argument as the one showing that Cohen generics are not minimal.)

$2r$ is terrible notation, though.
